# Http status code in response of php(Magento) web service developed for iOS app

Tags: php, web-services, magento, ios6, http-status-codes

I am developing a iOS app like eBay. For this web service developer is using Magento. He developed the web service for Login. Following are the situations :

1) If I send valid login credentials , he returns me logged in used info in response + a flag as result = true & in this case http status code is 200.

2) If I send wrong password , he returns me a flag as result = false &  http status code is 200.

Basically I don't want to depend on result flag because , if developer changed the result flag name then iOS app can't recognize that. So I want to follow standards which is a http status codes.

My question is , in 2nd situation is it right to send 200 as http status code ? I think he should send me 401 ? Correct me if I am wrong.
If I am right , is there any way to send http status code from php code so that I can check the http status code on iOS side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is , in 2nd situation is it right to send 200 as http status code ? I think he should send me 401 ? Correct me if I am wrong.

That depends on your needs. Write the specification, then implement accordingly. If you say 401, take 401.

> If I am right , is there any way to send http status code from php code so that I can check the http status code on iOS side ?

Sure, there is. Luckily this [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4797274/367456) so the info is already on this website and we do not need to answer it again.

Answer (score 5):

You can add custom response status code in Magento by,

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.0','404',true);
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.0','200',true);
```

where $this is controller action object, code works in your magento controller