# how to make a AJAX friend request system using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I want to do a MySQL,PHP,jQuery AJAX and JSON based friend request system like in Facebook.
I have prepared the JSON results but I don't know how to do the jQuery part can anyone please help me here is the JSON results

this one when u have error

```
{ "status":"error", "message":"Invalid Attempt" }
```

if you are already friends

```
{
"status":"error",
"message":"Already Friends"
}
```

and for success

```
{
"status":"success",
"message":"Request sent"
}
```

after success message I want to hide the div 
HTML structure is

```
<div class="comment" id="uid-2">
    <a class="avatar" href="http://mysitecom/u/remya">
      <img src="http://mysitecom/uploads/avatars/remya_XysseWQ.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="author" href="http://mysitecom/u/remya">Remya Prakash</a>
      <div class="text">
      <a class="author" href="javascript:;" id="2">Send Request</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Return the status as http header, 201 for success, 409 for a friend that already exists and 400 for invalid attempt. Then, the response doesn't even need to be a json object, but plain text that you can show to the user.

```
 <div class="text">
      <a class="author" id="2" href="javascript:void(0)">Send Request</a>
      <div id="result"></div> 
  </div>
```

...

```
<script>

$('.author').click(function(){
  $.post('ajax-friend-request-url',{ 'id': this.id })
     .done(function(){
           $(this).hide();
           $('#result').css('background-color', 'green');                 
         })
     .fail(function(){
           $('#result').css('background-color', 'red');                
         })
     .always(function(data){
           $('#result').text(data);
         });
    });
</script>
```

`http_response_code ([ int $response_code ] )` is the php function that can be used for setting the status header

Comment: I don't think there is a function called `http_response_code()` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797274/how-to-send-a-status-code-in-php-without-maintaining-an-array-of-status-names