# .htaccess show 404, 403, 500, error pages via PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, errordocument

How can I make .htaccess display errors from a PHP file? I mean when I search a non-existing file .htaccess should show me an error page from error.php, but error.php needs a parameter with the error code.

**NOTE:** .htaccess should show the error directly on the current url without redirecting. Can I do this or it is impossible? Are there any other ways?

Comment: you can also do within the same page using php headers

Comment: @Naeem What do you mean? I need to display 404, 500 errors, how can I do it within the same page???

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797274/how-to-send-a-status-code-in-php-without-maintaining-an-array-of-status-names

Comment: A clean and comprehensive solution: https://paulund.co.uk/use-htaccess-to-redirect-custom-error-pages

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for `ErrorDocument`.

In your .htaccess specify the codes you want to handle, like:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
```

And in error.php, handle the error codes like:

```
<?php
    $code = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'];
    $codes = array(
        403 => 'Forbidden',
        404 => 'Not Found',
        500 => 'Internal Server Error'
    );
    $source_url = 'http'.((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') ? 's' : '').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (array_key_exists($code, $codes) && is_numeric($code)) {
        die("Error $code: {$codes[$code]}");
    } else {
        die('Unknown error');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Custom 403 errors
ErrorDocument 403 your-path/403.php

//Custom 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 your-path/404.php

//Custom 500 errors
ErrorDocument 500 your-path/500.php
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of what the above has to do with the question asked. How does it relate to the requested `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Sorry, but such approach redirect user on error to related php page, I need to display an error on the go.

Comment: This *is* what you need. You can make these pages act exactly as you're asking - for eample they can all be symlinked to the same file which inspects the env vars (e.g. `$_SERVER`) to figure out which error to display.

Comment: Wrong syntax. Relative paths are not allowed. The paths in your example should start with /

Answer (score 0):

When you reference an error page in .htacess, all your doing is a redirect:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.htm
```

Change that to `error.php?code=404` and then pick that up in `error.php` using:

```
if($_GET['code'] == '404') {
    include('404.php');
}
```

Voila!

Comment: "all your doing is a redirect" - a "redirect" implies a 3xx external redirect - which this is not. When an `ErrorDocument` is triggered it is an "internal subrequest". You also don't need to explicitly pass the HTTP status code, since this is available in the `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']` superglobal.