# php - Laravel in shared hosting give me "Internal Server Error"

Tags: php, laravel

in my hosting I have a few pages in folders inside of public_html.

So, I need upload a Laravel project in a new folder for access like this: "www.mypage.com/laravelproject". My problem is that I create a folder laravelproject and I put all the laravel project inside this, but give me:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /laravelproject/ on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

And if i try enter to: "www.mypage.com/laravelproject/public" I receive this error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.

The hosting give me this errors that produce the project. The project name is "eysa", so I want access it like: "www.mydomain.com/eysa":

> [Thu Sep 14 14:31:54 2017] [alert] [client 190.19.102.99]
>   /var/www/vhost/example.com/home/html/eysa/public/.htaccess: Option
>   MultiViews not allowed here [Thu Sep 14 14:31:54 2017] [error] [client
>   190.19.102.99] File does not exist: /var/www/vhost/example.com/home/errors/500.html [Thu Sep 14
>   14:31:54 2017] [error] [client 190.19.102.99] File does not exist:
>   /var/www/vhost/example.com/home/html/favicon.ico, referer:
>   http://example.com/eysa/public [Thu Sep 14 14:31:54 2017] [error]
>   [client 190.19.102.99] File does not exist:
>   /var/www/vhost/example.com/home/errors/404.html, referer:
>   http://example.com/eysa/public

I need help!

Thanks!

Comment: What does your error log say? Apache error.log and laravel.log

Comment: Do you have access to ssh?

Comment: @mwweb hi, the domain/hosting don't have ssh

Comment: The `public` directory should be the document root. The `Internal Server Error` is likely a config issue such as database connection etc. Check your log files.

Comment: @fubar hi, these logs are in my hosting? Or I can see it in my ftp?

Comment: some web hostings puts your log file into your root directory or under a folder called error_logs or something similar to that. Most likely something wrong with your web.config / .htaccess file

Comment: @GeorgeQ hi, I contact to my hosting because they don't give me permissions to see error logs. When I have it, I post it. btw thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @R.Rio, before planning to put a Laravel application in shared hosting, please take a proper research and read the guidelines on deploying it - such as [this](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e). You will expose your configuration and credentials if you deploy it carelessly..

Comment: i think you need to create a folder "sampleProject" inside public_html then put your laravel app there and you can access it like www.mypage.com/sampleProject/public

Comment: @JunaidAhmad hi, i make this but return me: "500 Internal server error"

Comment: @siniradam hi, my hosting finally give me the error log. I edit the main post and I put it, can you take a look please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so let's tear down your log file

Here is your main problem your server configuration does not allow to use MultiViews, removing that from your .htaccess file probably should fix the issue.

> [Thu Sep 14 14:31:54 2017] [alert] [client 190.19.102.99]
>   /var/www/vhost/example.com/home/html/eysa/public/.htaccess: Option
>   MultiViews not allowed here

Your server looking for your custom error page but cannot found, you can [define yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869504/htaccess-show-404-403-500-error-pages-via-php) in .htaccess as well ;

> [Thu Sep 14 14:31:54 2017] [error] [client
>   190.19.102.99] File does not exist: /var/www/vhost/example.com/home/errors/500.html

Your browser tries to get favicon.ico but cannot be found in root.

> [Thu Sep 14 14:31:54
>   2017] [error] [client 190.19.102.99] File does not exist:
>   /var/www/vhost/example.com/home/html/favicon.ico, referer:
>   http://example.com/eysa/public

This is also almost identical error with the one above, same comment applies.

> [Thu Sep 14 14:31:54 2017] [error]
>   [client 190.19.102.99] File does not exist:
>   /var/www/vhost/example.com/home/errors/404.html, referer:
>   http://example.com/eysa/public

Seems like your server only allows MultiViews on your root folder, if laravel requires this you can create a sub-domain or create a virtual folder if your hosting allows.

Comment: thanks! I will try to create a subdomain and put all the project here

Comment: no, this don't work. I create the subdomain but don't work. Finally i pay for another hosting and all work perfect. thanks!!

Comment: @R.Rio did you tried removing MultiViews from your .htaccess what was the result?