# Does timber have default 500 template like it has 404?

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber, trellis

I am using timber starter theme for my wordpress website along with twig templates. I can render 404 template given by timber for 404 errors. I want to know if timber provides or handles even 500 error? 
I want to show custom error page for the 500 errors. 
Any help please?
Thanks in advance!

What I tried already-
similar to 404 templates I created two files as 500.php and 500.twig which has my custom error template. However this template is not rendered when I get 500 error.

Comment: You could try using .htaccess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869504/htaccess-show-404-403-500-error-pages-via-php

Answer (score 0):

Because 500 errors are server errors, so this would need to be configured "underneath" the WordPress install/layer. Even without Timber, WordPress doesn't provide this kind of customization. You may be able to set this with Apache or Nginx