# Change 404 Error with .htaccess: Custom 404 error page

Tags: .htaccess

How can i change the 404 Error Page with .htaccess.
Actually, i have an htaccess file that contains rewrite rules.
In brief,i want to customize 401, 402, 403, 404 and 405 error pages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess show 404, 403, 500, error pages via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869504/htaccess-show-404-403-500-error-pages-via-php)

Answer (score 1):

> My reputation does not allow me to comment, so i have to answer.

Example:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

#
# .htaccess content
#

ErrorDocument 403 403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /AnyDir/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /OtherDir/500.php
```

Comment: Why comment, when you can answer? (+1)