# How can I catch all DOMExceptions thrown in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, iframe, frames

I would like to create a method that returns an iframe's URL if the parent page is allowed to (because it is under the same domain), and return a falsy value if the parent page is not allowed to do so.

I have the following code hosted by https://cjshayward.com:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <iframe name="test_frame" id="test_frame"
        src="https://cjshayward.com"></iframe>
        <script>
            setTimeout(function()
                {
                try
                    {
                    console.log(window.frames.testframe.location.href);
                    }
                catch(error)
                    {
                    console.log('Not able to load.');
                    });
                }, 1000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `setTimeout()` is used because if I specify an iframe and then immediately have JavaScript attempt to load the page's URL, it will load a URL of `about:blank`.

But when I change the URL to the script in the same place to another domain (that has no restrictions on e.g. loading contents in a frame), Firefox logs the string specified in the catch block, and still logs an uncaught DOMException:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <iframe name="test_frame" id="test_frame"
        src="https://orthodoxchurchfathers.com"></iframe>
        <script>
            setTimeout(function()
                {
                try
                    {
                    console.log(window.frames.testframe.location.href);
                    }
                catch(error)
                    {
                    console.log('Not able to load.');
                    });
                }, 1000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the first case, it logs https://cjshayward.com. In the second case, it logs "Not able to load," but still shows an uncaught DOMException in the log.

How can I make a function that returns the iframe's location.href if it is available, and returns something falsy like an empty string if the same is not available due to browser security restrictions?

Or, taking a slight step back, is the logged DOMException unimportant? If I replace the console.log() calls with return calls from within a function, will my code be able to use the return value as the iframe's URL if such is available and a falsy value if it is not available?

TIA,

--UPDATE--

I have the present revised version of the test program:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <iframe name="test_frame" id="test_frame"
        src="https://orthodoxchurchfathers.com"></iframe>
        <script>
            window.onerror = (e) =>
                {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('#' + e + '#');
                };
            setTimeout(function()
                {
                try
                    {
                    console.log(window.frames.binary.location.href);
                    }
                catch(e)
                    {
                    console.log('Not able to load.');
                    }
                 }, 1000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It logs "Not able to load," but it displays an uncaught DOMException. It does not log any line between hashes.

Comment: Just use `.htaccess` to redirect DOM Errors to certain documents. If you want an empty value, just redirect it to an empty page. You can read how to do it here: [.htaccess show 404, 403, 500, error pages via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869504/htaccess-show-404-403-500-error-pages-via-php) It's redirecting to a PHP file there, but might just as well be a simple html file or something.

Comment: @icecub I have used Apache to set [custom error pages](https://cjshayward.com/asfdjldas), and see how a .htaccess could be used to do that. However, I am looking for something purely in JavaScript, without loading additional pages unless I specifically program a redirect. It is not clear to me how specifying an Apache redirect would inform a pure-JavaScript solution about whether a frame's location.href is available and return the string if it is available or an empty string if it is not.

Comment: There is no pure javascript solution for this. The browser dictates how it handles http errors. That's why Chrome lets you play the dinosaur game if you get a 404 error returned. Javascript can't catch or handle those errors. The only way to control what happens is to catch the error before it's sent to the client's browser. Which means that you'll have to catch it server side and make sure it's never sent to the client's browser in the first place.

Comment: There _might_ actually be a way to make it work, which is using Ajax. If you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42758604/check-if-online-resource-is-reachable-with-javascript-not-requiring-the-the-sam), you might be able to use that code to query the website and decide how to proceed based on the response code.

Comment: I don't have much time just now, but it seems to me they do report the error on both sides of the `Location` object, i.e., on your doc, and in the iframe's one. I guess adding `onerror=()=>true` in the embedee would hide that message, but it's probably not easy to set, and maybe better to just ignore. Note that you could avoid the need for throwing by first checking if you have access to the frame's `contentDocument`, that one returns null instead of throwing.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you; attempting to access the frame's contentDocument threw for me. Is there any other way to programmatically check if I have access to the iframe?

Comment: Ah, right, you are getting the `contentWindow` through `frames[name]` already, I missed that. You need to access the `contentDocument` from the `<iframe>` element: https://jsfiddle.net/hnge6f0q/

Answer (score 1):

Just use a normal **window.onerror** event to catch it...

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body> 

<script>

window.onerror=(e)=>{alert(e);};

setTimeout(function(){

 console.log(window.frames.testframe.location.href);

},2000);

</script>

<iframe name="test_frame" id="test_frame" src="https://orthodoxchurchfathers.com"></iframe>

</body></html>
```

If you want to go further you can also...

```
window.onunhandledrejection=(e)=>{alert(e.reason);};
```

Or maybe *e.reason.message* ? ...can't remember.

*try > catch* doesn't work with console issues.

Comment: Thank you; could you view the updated question and make any updates?