# Setting HTTP response status code in PHP using header('HTTP/1.1 <status-code>')?

Tags: php, http, http-headers, http-response-codes

I mostly see the response code being set like this:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
```

But the below also seems to work fine

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404');
```

wanted to know if it absolutely necessary to specify the status code description like `OK`, `Not Found` etc. I would like to avoid specifying since my status code is a variable and I would need to maintain a table of some sort mapping every single status code to the status code description. Please find the the code I am using below.

```
$status = 404; //or any other response code
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : 'HTTP/1.0');
header($protocol." $status");
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797274/how-to-send-a-status-code-in-php-without-maintaining-an-array-of-status-names ?

Comment: The reason phrase (the thing after statuscode-and-whitespace) is not optional, but can be empty.

Comment: @Syscall that page does have info on various ways to set the status code, However, I have a more specific question and want to understand if there are any pitfalls in implementing it this way (because I haven't come across this form in documentation)

Comment: @JulianReschke apologies, but that statement seems contradictory? if you can elaborate that would be great.

Comment: even if the reason phrase is empty, you still need a trailing whitespace in the status line; see RFC 7230, Section 3.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is sent, even if you don't provide it.

In the [PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src), we can see how it works.

In [`sapi/litespeed/lsapi_main.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/litespeed/lsapi_main.c#L318), a list of code/message is stored.

```
static const http_error http_error_codes[] = {
   {100, "Continue"},
   {101, "Switching Protocols"},
   {200, "OK"},
   // ...
   {403, "Forbidden"},
   {404, "Not Found"},
   // ...
   {0,   NULL}
};
```

Then, in the `sapi_lsapi_send_headers_like_cgi()`, from `sapi_lsapi_send_headers()`, the status is converted to integer and message is found in the `http_error` structure (many lines ommited below) :

```
if (SG(sapi_headers).http_response_code != 200)
{
    // ...
    if (SG(sapi_headers).http_status_line &&
         (s = strchr(SG(sapi_headers).http_status_line, ' ')) != 0 &&
         (s - SG(sapi_headers).http_status_line) >= 5 &&
         strncasecmp(SG(sapi_headers).http_status_line, "HTTP/", 5) == 0
    ) {
        len = slprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Status:%s", s);
        response_status = atoi((s + 1));
    }
    // ...
            http_error *err = (http_error*)http_error_codes;
            while (err->code != 0) {
                if (err->code == SG(sapi_headers).http_response_code) {
                    break;
                }
                err++;
            }
            if (err->msg) {
                len = slprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Status: %d %s", SG(sapi_headers).http_response_code, err->msg);
            } else {
                len = slprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Status: %d", SG(sapi_headers).http_response_code);
            }
        //...
```

Then the function `LSAPI_SetRespStatus_r()` hold this information and finally, the function `LSAPI_FinalizeRespHeaders_r()` send the finalized header informations.

The most [interesting line](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/litespeed/lsapi_main.c#L413) is (store the message from the `http_error`) :

```
len = slprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Status: %d %s", SG(sapi_headers).http_response_code, err->msg);
```

For information, see also the simple structure of `http_error` :

```
typedef struct _http_error {
  int code;
  const char* msg;
} http_error;
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. let me go through the code and understand this better. Would you know if this behaviour is version independent?

Comment: @applecodervinegar This code was added in the version 7.2.

Comment: I tested in PHP/7.1.33 and it was working fine without the message

Comment: Right. Just checked in PHP source code : before 7.2, the function was `sapi_cgi_send_headers()`. So it works at least as of PHP 5.6 (checked).

Comment: Also, note that the _"Reason-Phrase is intended for the human user. The client is not required to examine or display the Reason-Phrase."_ ([Hypertext Transfer Protocol §6.1.1](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html))